# Can web sockets be used today without a .NET 4.5 host?

Tags: javascript, websocket, windows-8, socket.io

I'm looking to connect my WinJS app to mobile browser clients via a cloud service that everyone connects to using web sockets.

I built a solution using socket.io that works well as long as my node.js server is hosted on localhost :) When I deploy my server to Azure, the Windows 8 app returns an error saying it can't load external content in a local context (after calling socket.io's connect()).

Looking at the web sockets sample on MSDN, I think that I should use the built-in functionality in Windows.Networking.Sockets for at least what's between my app and the public cloud service as it won't try to load external resources.

**My question is:** what are the options for the other end of the tunnel? Does it require a .NET 4.5 host with IIS 8 (since IIS 7 doesn't support WS)? I don't think those exist today yet, so I'm wondering what the development story is here.

Depending on what I end up using for the server, I think I'll have to use socket.io again or SignalR to serve the clients (most won't support web sockets and I need a good cross-browser library :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question)
I was behind a proxy that didn't allow the web socket connection from socket.io in my Win8 app through, and so it fell back on a method that required loading external resources.

Bypassing that problematic proxy, the connection works fine and I can use socket.io from my app as intended. I'm hosting the other end on Azure (per the node.js + socket.io tutorial they provide) and it works. I still don't know what a developer wanting to use the built-in web sockets library should use for a host, but I imagine we have to wait for IIS 8 to be out.

Now I'm left to verify that the app can pass certification with this library.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend is a **NodeJS** app, you don't *need* an **IIS Server** or anything related to the .NET Framework.

A list of hosting providers is maintained by NodeJS' author at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting (The list might be outdated as I don't see Azure there).

I don't see why your server shouldn't work when deployed to Azure. Are you using `npm install azure`?

---

I have a feeling that you are confusing yourself regarding **Web Sockets** and **Socket.io**.

Socket.io is a realtime transport framework that *might* or *might not* use Web Sockets for its transport on the client-side based on the client's browser.

Refer: [FAQ — Socket.IO](http://socket.io/#faq)

Comment: I might not have explained myself properly. I was looking for a hosting solution that supports the web sockets implementation in WinRT. I fixed my problem and I'll write an answer to close the topic. Thanks for your explanation though.